# copy a file from site collection "Shared Document" to another web "target library"

Tags: development

Is there a way programatically copy a file from source to target dob lib? Source would be always static. target may vary.

Comment: Are you using 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example that should work either on 2007 or 2010

http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/12/move-sharepoint-document-library-files.html

Comment: Thanks for finding the solution. I was under the time crunch so I just used spfile.add method and adding files from local.

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2010, you can use the Content Organizer as well. It will route the items to the appropriate location based on metadata and rules. This would save you the need to use code when you can do it out of the box.